# While Compiling "strlcpy.h" is not found

Tags: c++, g++, root-framework

I'm trying to compile C++ Code using g++ and using the CERN ROOT Framework. I've got the folowing error message, while compiling.

```
 In file included from /usr/include/root/TObject.h:31:0,
             from /usr/include/root/TNamed.h:26,
             from /usr/include/root/TDirectory.h:25,
             from /usr/include/root/TDirectoryFile.h:25,
             from /usr/include/root/TFile.h:25,
             from neutralino_root.cpp:13:
/usr/include/root/Rtypes.h:36:68: fatal error: strlcpy.h: No such file or directory
#include <strlcpy.h>    // part of string.h on systems that have it
                                                                ^
    compilation terminated.
```

Has anyone an idea, why "strlcpy.h" is not found?
Thanks for help,
Simon

Comment: It's not a c++ standard header. Are you compiling on an OSX system?

Comment: It's an OS X header.

Comment: Did you perhaps omit a `./configure` stage before building ?

Comment: ROOT should bring its own `strlcpy.h` if needed (was added to the source in 2010). For me it is in `/where/root/is/installed/include/strlcpy.h`. Is the file present for you in the directory indicated by `root-config --incdir`? Do compile with the `gcc` arguments suggested by `root-config --cflags`?